# Cannot implement Core Data validation in Category

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I am implementing a validation function in core data as follows:

```
- (BOOL)validateMovementId:(id)value error:(NSError **)error {

NSString * idValue = (NSString *) value;
Movement * m = [Movement loadMovement:idValue context:self.managedObjectContext];

if(m != nil)
    return NO;

return YES;  }
```

I am using a category on the underlying core data model class so that I can rewrite these classes automatically using XCode without loosing my additions.  This works fine for all methods except the above method, which gives me an EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the method itself when I save the managed context.

Here's the thing: moving this function out of the category and into the base class fixes the issue.  I'm guessing that this is because when Core Data goes to save the context, it's not using my categories but the base classes instead and so the pointer goes invalid.  Is there any way to implement validation using a category, or is it necessary to subclass the autogenerated objects to do this and still retain the ability to rewrite them automatically using XCode?

Comment: Can you say more about what you mean by "the above method [...] gives me an EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the method itself when I save the managed context"?

Comment: When I call the save: method on the current NSManagedObjectContext, this triggers the data to be committed to the persistent data store. Core data automatically attempts to call the validate<Key>:error: methods that I have defined.  When defined in a category on the automatically generated classes, execution terminates with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception with execution breaking on the method definition (i.e. XCode shows execution halted on the line where the validation method is first defined).  My assumption is that because I am using a category, the function pointer is nil.

Comment: I think that's got to be wrong. I use categories for all CD stuff and they work fine. This method seems kind of nutty though: should you be looking up an object inside a validate? My guess is that the mom is null or something.

Comment: The point of this validation routine is to check that the user entered packageId is not already in use by another record.  I can attempt the function without the lookup and see if that makes a different, but remember I don't get an error within the method itself.   The validate function is being called by Core Data, why would the object itself be null?  Any other ideas what is going wrong here?  Remember that if I move this function to a subclass on the core data model, it works a-o-k.